# Hotel reservation Occupied Room Query Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Entity **Room** and **Reservation**

Room=Room_id,Rtype,**Occupied**(Bit column)

Reservation =Res_id,Room_id,CheckinDate,CheckoutDate.

How to update Occupied bit column to 1 when a room is reserved in **Reservations** table?I think its a trigger.but how?code snippet as I am new to this.

Someone suggested using check out date as Null.If null then update Occupied to 1.
HElp!!

Comment: You don't need to set a bit for this.  You simply need to structure a query to look at reservations and calculate whether a room is free on a given date or dates.

Comment: Seems to me like a bad design. you can calculate the Occupied bit by a simple query to the reservation table.

Comment: Elaborate please.Even if I change it into Status then what do i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using a static placement field like the Occupied one you have is that the value will change depending on the date you are reviewing.  For example: Room A is unoccupied now, but is reserved two days from now for a 3 night stay, if you change the Occupied field to 1 then it will incorrectly show up as Occupied if someone tries to check-in today.

You will also have the problem of changing the Occupied field back to 0 when the room isn't in use - this is creating more work than necessary.

As mentioned in the comments it would be best to not have the Occupied field at all and instead create queries that will show when a room is available or not.  The query can really vary depending on what you want, below is a sample query that creates a stored procedure that can be used to find available rooms during a date range:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckRoomAvailability
    @NewCheckInDate DATETIME
    @NewCheckOutDate DATETIME
AS

SELECT r.Room_ID, r.Rtype
FROM room AS r
INNER JOIN reservation as re
ON r.room_id = re.room_id
WHERE
    (@NewCheckINDate < re.CheckinDate 
    OR
    @NewCheckInDate > re.CheckoutDate)
    AND
    (@NewCheckOutDate < re.CheckinDate 
    OR
    @NewCheckOutDate > re.CheckoutDate)
GO
```

Then to execute this stored procedure:

```
EXEC CheckRoomAvailability([Check-In Date],[Check-Out Date])
```

Just enter the desired dates into the statement.

Comment: is it for sql server 2014?

Answer (score 0):

```
select checkoutdate from Reservation;
```

Put checkoutdate on a variable.

```
if checkoutdate == null then
update Room set occupied = 1;
```